# Error while recreating a deleted site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I get this error after I try to recreate a site collection which just have been deleted.

> System.ArgumentException: Another site already exists at http://localhost. Delete this site before attempting to create a new site with the same URL, choose a new URL, or create a new inclusion at the path you originally specified.

I have deleted everything, dont see the site collections anymore in management center, and content DB's are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a site collection, it deleted for end user but still exist in the sharepoint recylce bin called Central admin Recycle Bin(Accessable via PowerShell). in order to compeltly remove a site collection,please follow these steps.

- delete a site collection.
- Now run the [Get-SpDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316.aspx) on server and you will see the recent deleted site collection.
- Now run the [Remove-SpDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286317.aspx) against your site collection.
- Now go to `central admin > Monotring > Job Definitation > click on the` **Gradual Site Delete** and Click run now.
- wait for 5 min and Now try to create new site collection using the old name.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that this site collection still resides in the site collection "Recycling Bin" and retained for 90 days. Please verify that this item has been cleared from the Recycling Bin.

For more information, you can see the following [site](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-or-delete-a-site-collection-3a3d7ab9-5d21-41f1-b4bd-5200071dd539) upon what happens after a site collection is deleted.